# How to get only specific elements of list in racket

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

Input:

```
'(("may 001" 75 72) 
  ("may 002" 75 75) 
  ("may 003" 70 73) 
  ("june 101" 55 55) 
  ("june 104" 55 54) 
  ("aug 201" 220 220))
```

Desired output:

```
'(("may 001" 75 72) ("may 002" 75 75) ("may 003" 70 73))
```

How do I achieve this? I only want the `may` terms.

Comment: It's important to show the desired output, but I think you need to show the original *input*, too.

Comment: output=>original output

Comment: Yes, I see that you're showing *actual* output and  *desired* output.  That's a good thing.  But what's the input?  What's the function that's producing it?  Was the original input a list of 100 elements?  How did it already get cut down to a list of 6 elements?  You're not showing us the whole problem, and you're not presenting any code that has a bug, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [racket/scheme filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504302/racket-scheme-filtering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" way of getting specific element based on their values is to use [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=filter#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) with a suitable predicate.

Something along these lines:

```
(define (may? str)
  (string=? "may" (substring str 0 3)))

(define (only-may ls)
  (filter (lambda (x) (may? (car x))) ls))
```

Answer (score 0):

To be useful, we probably want a function that takes the name of a month and a list of records and returns a list of the matching records:

```
#lang racket

;; string ListOf(ListOf(String Int Int)) -> ListOf(ListOf(String Int Int))
(define (get-month target-month list-of-record)

  ;; ListOf(String Int Int) -> Boolean
  (define (record-matches? record)
    (regexp-match target-month (first record)))
  (filter record-matches? list-of-record))
```

Then we can use it in queries such as:

```
"scratch.rkt"> (get-month "may" 
                          '(("may 001" 75 72) 
                            ("may 002" 75 75) 
                            ("may 003" 70 73) 
                            ("june 101" 55 55) 
                            ("june 104" 55 54) 
                            ("aug 201" 220 220)))
'(("may 001" 75 72) ("may 002" 75 75) ("may 003" 70 73))
"scratch.rkt"> (get-month "april" 
                          '(("may 001" 75 72) 
                            ("may 002" 75 75) 
                            ("may 003" 70 73) 
                            ("june 101" 55 55) 
                            ("june 104" 55 54) 
                            ("aug 201" 220 220)))
'()
```